# Salvar formulário "Registro de Presença" - Múltiplos Inputs Radios

Tags: php

Olá, pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para registrar a presença dos acadêmicos de uma instituição de ensino, os dados do formulário (Curso, disciplinas e alunos) eu estou buscando por web service do sistema de ensino deles, vejam a imagem abaixo de como ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para salvar os três primeiros inputs é tranquilo, o meu problema é que não consegui pensar em como vou salvar esta lista de INPUTS RADIO dentro da tabela, pois os NAMES dos inputs eu preenchi dinamicamente com os ID's dos alunos, segue o exemplo abaixo:

ALUNO 1:

```html
<input type="radio" name="5334" value="1" /> <!--(Esse representa o "Presente")-->
<input type="radio" name="5334" value="0" /> <!--(Esse representa o "Ausente")-->
```

ALUNO 2:

```html
<input type="radio" name="5452" value="1" /> <!--(Esse representa o "Presente")-->
<input type="radio" name="5452" value="0" /> <!--(Esse representa o "Ausente")-->
```

Por favor se alguém puder me dar uma luz fico muito grato.

**OBS: Uso o PHP 7, apache 2.4 e Laravel 5.4 como framework.**

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua pergunta direito, mas você poderia percorrer todos os elementos do form com o `.each` do `jQuery`: `$("form").each(function(){
    $(this).find(':input')
});` e, baseado no `name` do elemento, fazer o seu `INSERT`/`UPDATE`

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa passar os dados em formato de array, não sei bem como explicar mas você pode criar um input com o mesmo name e salvar os dados no php depois através de um `foreach`

No html:

```
<input type="radio" name="ausente[][id_do_aluno]" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="presente[][id_do_aluno]" value="0" />
```

No PHP:

```
$valores = $_POST['ausente'];

foreach($valores as $valor){
   //aqui você terá uma array com os valores, use-os como desejado
   var_dump($valor);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, sua ideia encaixou como uma luva, vlw por exemplificar o html do php, consegui solucionar meu problema, abraços.

Comment: Disponha, Abraços :)